Cisco catalyst 3750 switch fault
Please I need any help or advice I can get. My switch was working fine all of a sudden the computers connected to the switch stop receiving connections. Upon checking the switch, I discovered all the lights on the switchports are off.
So I disconnected all the cables and unmounted it from the stack so I could have a closer look, to further discovered the system light keeps blinking green for a very long period of time(about 4-5 minutes) after which all the LED light (SYS,RPS,MASTR,STAT,DUPLEX,SPEED,STACK) stay green for about 4 seconds and after only the SYS,MASTR,STAT LED lights remains steady green.
Occasionally all the 48 ports stay steady green for about 2 seconds after which it turn to steady orange for about 2 seconds and dissappear.
I have tried a factory reset but it doesn't seem to work, I can't connect to the switch remotely, no vty lines or management ip have been configured. When I connect to the switch via a console cable no output is being displayed on putty, the screen is just dark.
Any help will be greatly appreciated
Thank you

If you get no serial console output, it is likely the power supply has failed or has a fault and the switch should be replaced. Cisco switches purchased from an authorized vendor may have lifetime support so you could contact Cisco support to arrange a replacement.

Thank you for your, I just a read a documentary online which I can't explicitly tell if it true or not but it says it is advisable to change cisco device every 3 to 5 years and the switch which has a fault has been operating for 5 years now going to 6 years. So I think it could actually be a hardware failure
